# Shoulda: Test validates_presence_of :on => :update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda

I'm using Shoulda in combination with Test::Unit on one of the projects I work on.  The issue I'm running into is that I recently changed this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :attribute_one, :attribute_two
end
```

to this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :attribute_one
  validates_presence_of :attribute_two, :on => :update
end
```

Previously, my (passing) tests looked like this:

```
class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should_validate_presence_of :attribute_one, :attribute_two
end
```

As far as I can tell, there is no parameter to `should_validate_presence_of` that will cause this test to continue to pass with the changes specified above.  Short of abandoning Shoulda when testing the requirement of `:attribute_two`, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that past I have just used a small custom should block to get around this problem:

```
should "require :attr_two on update" do
  mm = Factory(:my_model)
  mm.attr_two = nil
  mm.save
  assert_equal false, mm.valid?
  assert_equal("can't be blank", mm.errors.on(:attr_two))
 end
```

Hopefully shoulda will keep improving by allowing further AR validation options in the future. Let me know what you think, cheers.

Answer (score 8):

What about something like this? (for `shoulda-matchers-3.1.1`)

```
subject { FactoryGirl.build(:your_model) }
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:attribute_one) }
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:attribute_two).on(:update) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a solution similar to what tsdbrown suggested.  This type of test passes when I have:

```
validates_presence_of :attr_two
```

But the test fails if I change the model to:

```
validates_presence_of :attr_two, :on => :save
```

It fails because the :attr_two error is [] instead of ["can't be blank"]

Answer (score 2):

In Rspec you can do the following:

```
describe MyModelTest do
  describe "validations" do
    should_validate_presence_of :attribute_one

    context "on update" do
      subject { FactoryGirl.create(:my_model_test) }

      should_validate_presence_of :attribute_two
    end
  end
end
```