# Test validating presence of email fails with shoulda, passes with factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I'm testing that email is not required on the user model on update.

With FactoryGirl:

```
u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
u.email = nil
expect(u.save).to be_true
```

The test passes.

With shoulda:

```
should_not validate_presence_of(:email).on(:update)
```

The test fails with error:

```
Failure/Error: should_not validate_presence_of(:email)
Did not expect errors to include "can't be blank" when email is set to nil, got error:     can't be blank
```

Anyone have any thoughts on why this discrepancy occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what's happening.

The `should_not` test is using an implicit subject of `User.new`. In order to test `update` on this subject, it must first be saved, but saving will result in an error because of the validation on `create`.  The workaround is create/save a valid user object and to call `should_not validate_presence_of(...).on(:update)` explicitly on that object.

See the related [Shoulda: Test validates_presence_of :on => :update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009159/shoulda-test-validates-presence-of-on-update)

Comment: Sorry- I had to run earlier as well.

Thank you very much for all the help and the good answer. For reference, I found the .on(:update) here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/131 and in the links within. Thanks again.